# Delete duplicate rows except one

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am dealing with a table which has only two columns - `Address` and `DateEntered`. This table has several duplicate records with different `DateEntered`. Something like this:

```
Address       | DateEntered
--------------+---------------------    
10 Park Ave   | 5-6-2012
7 Sterling Rd | 7-8-2012
10 Park Ave   | 2-2-2010
10 Park Ave   | 5-20-2021
```

I would like to retain the address with the most recent date and get rid of the old ones. The result should be like this:

```
Address       | DateEntered
--------------+---------------
7 Sterling Rd | 7-8-2012
10 Park Ave   | 5-20-2021
```

Can you please help me build this query? I don't even know where to start. I was reading about Common Table Expressions but didn't reach anywhere.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a minimal reproducible example. Please refer to the following link:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
Please provide the following:  
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quick and easy via a `CTE` in concert with the window function `row_number()`

**Example or [dbFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=d9ad0f5ef5dacc21abb54a3db7e6e718)**

```
;with cte as ( 
    Select *
          ,RN = row_number() over (partition by address order by DateEntered Desc) 
     From YourTable
)
Delete from cte where RN>1
```

**The Updated Table**

```
Address         DateEntered
7 Sterling Rd   2012-07-08
10 Park Ave     2021-05-20
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply insert the results of maxing the date by address to a new table, then replace the old table with it:

```
SELECT Address, max(dateentered) as DateEntered
INTO deduped
FROM original
GROUP BY Address
```